# DTLgetvalueforkey works, but DTLfetch doesn't

Tags: datatool, catcodes, csv

In the following example `\DTLgetvalueforkey` retrieves the information without problem, while `\DTLfetch` fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Heading A, Heading B, Heading C
One,    Een,  1
Two,    Twee, 2
T_hree, Drie, 3
Four,   Vier, 4
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLloadrawdb
  [keys={HeadA,HeadB,HeadC}]
  {data}{data.csv}

\DTLdisplaydb{data}

\bigskip

% \DTLgetvalueforkey{<cmd>}{<key>}{<db name>}{<ref key>}{<ref value>}
% \DTLfetch{<db name>}{<col1 name>}{<col1 value>}{<col2 name>}

\textbf{Heading A} = `Two' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\datavalue}{HeadB}{data}{HeadA}{Two}\datavalue% Twee

\textbf{Heading A} = `Two' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLfetch{data}{HeadA}{Two}{HeadB}% Twee

\textbf{Heading A} = `T\_hree' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\datavalue}{HeadB}{data}{HeadA}{T\_hree}\datavalue% Drie

% Should be the same as above, but not found
\textbf{Heading A} = `T\_hree' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLfetch{data}{HeadA}{T\_hree}{HeadB}% Drie

\end{document}
```

Why is this? Can `\DTLfetch` be fixed to work here?

The problem is specific to the use of `_` inside CSV entries. The input I'm working with contains this, so there's very little I can do to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) mentions the following about `\DTLfetch`:

> `\DTLfetch{<db name>}{<col1 name>}{<col1 value>}{<col2 name>}`
>
> This fetches and displays the value for `<col2 name>` in the first row where the value of `<col1 name>` is `<col1 value>`. (Note that all arguments are expanded.)

Expansion here is causing the issue. To get around this, fetch for `T\noexpand\_hree` rather than `T\_hree`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Heading A, Heading B, Heading C
One,    Een,  1
Two,    Twee, 2
T_hree, Drie, 3
Four,   Vier, 4
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLloadrawdb
  [keys={HeadA,HeadB,HeadC}]
  {data}{data.csv}

\DTLdisplaydb{data}

\bigskip

% \DTLgetvalueforkey{<cmd>}{<key>}{<db name>}{<ref key>}{<ref value>}
% \DTLfetch{<db name>}{<col1 name>}{<col1 value>}{<col2 name>}

\textbf{Heading A} = `Two' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\datavalue}{HeadB}{data}{HeadA}{Two}\datavalue% Twee

\textbf{Heading A} = `Two' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLfetch{data}{HeadA}{Two}{HeadB}% Twee

\textbf{Heading A} = `T\_hree' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\datavalue}{HeadB}{data}{HeadA}{T\_hree}\datavalue% Drie

\textbf{Heading A} = `T\_hree' corresponds to \textbf{Heading B} =
\DTLfetch{data}{HeadA}{T\noexpand\_hree}{HeadB}% Drie

\end{document}
```

---

If you are searching based on content within a macro, as in

```
\def\Three{T\_hree}
\DTLfetch{data}{HeadA}{\Three}{HeadB}% Drie
```

you will still have a problem. Here you still need to avoid the expansion of `\_`. You can do this using grouping a `\let`ting `\_` to `\relax`:

```
\def\Three{T\_hree}
{\let\_\relax
\DTLfetch{data}{HeadA}{\Three}{HeadB}}% Drie
```

Other options include making `\_` [robust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764) (via [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) with `\robustify{\_}`, say).